If my workplace is temporarily closed, will I still be paid?
The power at my work has been out for 3 days and is expected to not be back in working order for a full week.
Am I legally required to be paid for the forced time off?
My workplace is in Virginia, in case the state matters.

Need more details. Are you an exempt (not eligible for overtime) or non-exempt (eligible for overtime) employee? A salaried exempt employee might get paid or have to use PTO, but an hourly non-exempt employee would typically only get paid for hours actually worked.

Depends on you contract. What does it say? What is your status? What policies does your company have?

Furlough is likely another possibility, but as others have said, there are many factors to consider.

Legal perspective for Germany: https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/88843/work-time-when-unable-to-work-due-to-power-outage-germany

@nvoigt - Germany and Virginia are very different regions.

@Donald but the German information may well have more common sense applied...

@nvoigt USA is very ........ in this sense, average USA money is x2 but Kündigungsfrist is... the day on which you are fired. And no legal reason is needed.

@SolarMike - Germany employment laws are not applicable to an employee working in Virginia

@Donald I never said they were, didn't you read what I wrote or just didn't understand?

@SolarMike - You said that German information might have more common sense applied, but I am not sure how that is relevant, if the author resides in Virginia.

I don't know if it's common here, but many StackExchange sites value answers relating to other jurisdictions, as other people in similar situations are likely to find them useful.

@gidds - Except these were comments not answers and something like this question is highly regionalized.

@Donald you should expect comments in the comments section and answers in the answers section...

@SolarMike—I am aware of that. I am not going to entertain this conversation. It cannot possibly be legitimate. German employment regulations would not have been relevant to somebody in Virginia.  It wouldn't be helpful to somebody in Virginia to get an answer focused on German employment laws.

I'm not sure what we are discussing here? I am aware that Virginia is not in Germany, that's why I explicitely said "Germany" and made it a comment, not an answer. I did not vote to close either. I fully expect someone else to answer for VA, USA. By the way: that is how Law.SE works, you can absolutely post an answer for VA there, too, adding a tag on top, so there is one question with lots of answers for each juristiction, instead of tons of duplicates only varying in juristiction.

I don't think this is "legal advice" as per the close reason, I think every professional HR person should know the answer to this question. There is no personalized advice on legal matters asked for.

I have reopened the question. Please note that "There is no legal framework, it is up to the company to decide" would be a valid answer to this question if that were indeed the case.

Hope you are safe and sound over there @Dwbark Ive seen pics and the storm hit strong over there. Please try to enhance your post or address things some folks have commented for clarification.

In the US, this is partially determined by federal law, partly by state law, and partly by company policy and/or ad hoc decision.
Federally, the Fair Labor Standards Act (FLSA) says an exempt employee has to be paid their salary for any week in which they worked. So a couple days closure, they get paid; a full business week closure; they don’t.  Non-exempt are out of luck. Here’s an explanation from a HR site. However, they can still make you burn PTO balance (Even into the negative) for those days, but you still get paid. And any work (telework, even answering business emails) counts as work which means the full week is paid.
Virginia does not appear to have any specific laws on the subject.  Employers do - like here is the Virginia government’s executive branch’s complicated rules on it.
And companies can just decide to, if they want.  Like the Alamo Drafthouse paid their employees (even non-exempt) to some degree during the COVID shutdown. The existence of government funding for a given disaster will affect this. You should ask them.

Every company should have a policy regarding what happens when the place of business cannot be used. It can be due to fire, flood, snow, power, communicable disease, police activity, or any one of dozen things.  If they don't have a policy, they will eventually have to have a policy because these types of situations aren't unusual.
The company policy may require/allow for working at a remote site. They may allow/require you to come into work and do busy work until the situation changes. They may also want you to come into work and  help cleanup the mess caused by the weather event.
But it is also possible that their policy is that they won't pay you if you can't do the work they hired you for.  They may also have a policy that can handle one or two days each year, but then if the situation will take weeks or months to resolve.
I once sat with all my coworkers in a dark office for a day; because they wouldn't pay us if we weren't in the office, but the power was too fragile to allow us to power on the servers. This was while I was working for a Government contractor located in Maryland, at a worksite in Washington DC.
There might be local law (state/city) but probably not, though more localities started thinking about this during COVID. There policy might be dictated by a union contract.
It will also depend on the nature of your employment. Salaried employees are the most likely to be paid, full time employees less likely. Part-time employees shouldn't be surprised if they aren't paid. Contractors are generally out of luck, unless it is in their contract.
I would start with your direct manager. If they don't know the the answer, then the question should be asked of HR. They might require you to use PTO. They might also allow you to work the missed hours over the next month to allow you to recapture the missed hours.
If you are an employee at another companies work location like a government contractor, the answer for your contract may be different than for the company you work for.

So do I understand it correctly that the USA on federal level, or the state of Virginia specifically, has no legal framework to cover this and it's only up to the company what they decide in their own policy. Their policy could be "sucks to be you, we won't pay if you cannot work"?

Which would make total sense. Being an at-will state, they could just fire everyone and re-employ all of them one week later to circumwent any legal framework on this. Just making sure that "no mention" means that it isn't there, not just "not mentioned" :)

This is not meant as a criticism, I simply don't know, I did not vote either way yet.

@nvoigt: I would guess (IANAL) that at the federal level this is entirely a matter of contract law. Whether individual states have any regulations on it, I don't know.

@nvoigt If this is really about what's legal, it should probably be migrated to [law.se], no?

@ColleenV While it would be on-topic at Law.SE, it doesn't mean it's off-topic here. The [legal] tag exists for a reason. The reasoning here is, does this require the skill of a specialized lawyer, or should some other professional in a company know about it. And in this case, this is (in my country) and certainly should be taught in business school. A law that so directly impacts a companies bottom line is not for legal scholars only, it's common knowledge of anybody wondering if they will be able to lead a profitable company. I don't mind if the OP requests it, but it's perfectly fine here.
